# Как работать с таблицей в MSWord из C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Есть шаблон документа, в котором есть таблица, но при необходимости требуется добавить новую строку в таблице, добавил. НО как обозначить в таблице границы(чтобы все границы таблицы было видно)? И при необходимости слово вписать в столбик/строку?

И как можно осуществить автоматическую нумерацию строк "номер по порядку"? Данный столбик подразумевается счетчик: 1,2,3,4...

```
var Dvname = textBox1.Text;
var Reason = textBox6.Text = "";
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;

try
{
    var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(TemplateFileName);
    ReplaceWordStub("Dvname", Dvname, wordDocument);
    ReplaceWordStub("Reason", Reason, wordDocument);
    Word.Table table = wordDocument.Tables[1];
    table.Rows.Add();
    wordDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\результат.doc");
    wordApp.Visible = true;
    wordDocument.PrintOut();
    wordDocument.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится, решил.

```
                    int point = 0; //счетчик для нумерация строк
                    var test = wordDocument.Tables[1]; //объявление таблицы из шаблоне(MS Word)
                    var row = test.Rows.Add(); //создание дополнительной строки
                    row.Cells[1].Range.Text = (++point).ToString(); //создание 1 столбика и его нумерация, согласно счетчику
                    row.Cells[2].Range.Text = "Необходимый текст"; //создание 2 столбика и ввод текста
                    row.Cells[3].Range.Text = "Необходимый текст"; //создание 3 столбика и ввод текста
                    row.Borders.Enable = 1; //создание границ в таблице (все границы)
```